# Is there a way to check if a certain repository is a fork?

Tags: git, rest, github, github-api

Title.
Working on a MSR Research and it would be very relevant to know if a certain repository is a fork of another one. Is there a flag or anything like this?

**edit**

Maybe my question was poorly made, but i wanted to know if there's a way to check it automatically. A boolean variable in the API like fork = True, for example.

Comment: No fool proof way. Due to the distributed nature of git, in a real sense, _every_ copy of a repo is a fork.

Comment: This Github API call https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository returns JSON where `{…, "fork": false, …}` Actually any call that returns data about repository(ies) return that flag.

Comment: That's what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this is specific to GitHub. Other hosting sites generally have the same concept (Bitbucket calls theirs a "fork" as well) but their APIs differ.

Answer (score 2):

It should appear near the name of the repository, something like:

[image]